# Comma-separated list of integers with max 5 elements

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match a comma separated list of integers, where the max number/amount of elements in the list should be 5.

F.e. `1,1,5,6,253` and `12` and `234,6,43` etc. are allowed but `21,512,65,123,65,12` (here the elements are already 6) is not allowed.

I've got `^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$` as to match the list of integers, but I am not sure how to restrict the max number of elements in the list.

I tried placing `{5}` before and after the `*` but both are wrong regex patterns.

Comment: Apply a minimum `^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+){0,4}$`

Comment: Or with `\d`: `^\d+(,\d+){0,5}$`